# Where to get information to correctly parse repeating groups in FIX?

Tags: fix-protocol

I am trying to extend my FIX parser to include repeating groups. I, myself, haven't dealt with repeating groups so I don't know where to get information about what fields are included in repeating groups.

For the first cut, I am going to ignore custom repeating groups and only rely on ones in the official FIX protocol.

Looks like FIX defines a 'NumInGroup' type to identify start of groups. However, I don't see where to get information about what fields are included (I'm looking mainly at the onix dictionaries and the htmlized spec on quickfixenginer.org).

For example, field 552, NoSides is of type NumInGroup. Once my parser sees this tag, it knows that a group has started. However, how does it know how much of the remaining data belongs to this group?

Comment: Have you read the FIX protocol spec?  Also, unfortunately, the only way to know what fields are in repeating groups is to supply a field dictionary ("data dictionary") to your program as input.  For instance, with QuickFIX, there is a config file field that specifies the path to a data dictionary.

Comment: Check the quickifx library and see how it does. That is the easiest and the surest way to do it.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier, I see that quickfixengine's xml files do contain the information I need (the html version doesn't seem to).